# Неожиданное поведение Pydantic моделей при их инициализации

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

Работаю с PyDantic моделями и заметил, что модели унаследованные от BaseModel не проверяют именованные параметры, в отличии от обычных экземпляров классов. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с похожим поведением. Полагаю, что у них дескрипторы классов как-то странно прописаны. Может есть инструментарий в самой библиотеке как-то на это повлиять?

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class OrdinaryModel:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class PydanticModel(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kws = {'a':34, 'b':323, 'c':54}
    ord_model = OrdinaryModel(**kws)
    pyd_model = PydanticModel(**kws)
    print(pyd_model.dict()) # Тут никакой ошибки нету
    print(ord_model.__dict__) # Здесь же выскакивает ожидаемая ошибка TypeError
```

Ошибка:

> `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'`

Comment: 1) Текст ошибок и трассу стека нужно писать 2) По трассе стека было бы видно, что ошибка возникает в `ord_model = OrdinaryModel(**kws)`

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о лишнем параметре `c` в конструкторе:

> `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'c'`

Причина в том, что код вида:

```
kws = {'a':34, 'b':323, 'c':54}
ord_model = OrdinaryModel(**kws)
```

Аналогичен:

```
ord_model = OrdinaryModel(a=34, b=323, c=54)
```

Но, т.к. у вас в конструкторе нет параметра `c`, то и получаете ожидаемую ошибку.

Как вариант, вы можете добавить магические параметры `*args, **kwargs`, чтобы не объявленные явно параметры попали в них.

Попробуйте:

```
class OrdinaryModel:
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kws = {'a':34, 'b':323, 'c':54}
    ord_model = OrdinaryModel(**kws)
    print(ord_model.__dict__)
    # {'a': 34, 'b': 323}
```

---

**PS.**

А в типе от `BaseModel` из `pydantic` нет заданного конструктора, значит он его заранее создал и, возможно, как раз через `**kwargs`

Comment: Как это работает с обычными моделями понятно. А вот за наблюдение про отсутствие конструктора в Pydantic модели, спасибо. Попробую переопределить конструктор в pydantic модели, может поможет.